# Find the time between two events by customer id

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-mining, pandas, pattern-recognition

I need to find a customer has bought P1, and after how many days customer will buy P2. 
I am unable to find the days between order of P1 and the next order of P2 by the same customer.

I have data as shown below.

```
Customer ID   Order_Date   Product  
       C-87   11/20/2018        P2  
       C-87    7/25/2018        P1  
       C-87    7/19/2019        P1      
       C-87     8/2/2018        P2  
       C-87    12/9/2019        P1  
        ...          ...       ...
       C-22    9/22/2018        P2  
       C-22     9/4/2018        P2  
       C-22    1/15/2018        P1  
       C-22     9/5/2019        P2  
       C-22    3/20/2018        P1
```

Comment: It doesn't seems like a data science problem but some basic data manipulation.

Comment: @lcrmorin if not on this site, where do you suggest they post this question? I would argue that "basic data manipulation" is the core on which data science is built

Comment: Yes « basic data manipulation » is the core on which data science is built. But as is, it is unclear to me that this question is about data science instead of basic data manipulation. Stack overflow might be more appropriate for exemple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split it into two dataframe containing only one of P1 and P2 first.

```
df1 = df[df.index[df['Product'] == 'P1'].tolist()]
df2 = df[df.index[df['Product'] == 'P2'].tolist()]
```

And then marge df1 and df2 on Customer ID and Product

```
df1.merge(df2, 'inner', left_on=['Customer ID', 'Product'], right_on=['Customer ID', 'Product'], copy=False)
```